# Recommended hash function for overwriting NSObject's hash method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hash

What's a good hash function for overwriting NSObject's hash method in your custom classes?

Comment: Why do you think you need to override `hash`?  If you do, it is generally because you explicitly want to hash based on whatever data is stored in your object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a good community wiki page discussing overwriting the functions [Implementing -hash / -isEqual: / -isEqualTo...: for Objective-C collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112373/implementing-hash-isequal-isequalto-for-objective-c-collections).
And there is an implementation on one of the linked articles [Best practices for overriding isEqual: and hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash/254380#254380).