# Translating operator== in C++ to Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, operators

I am transcribing some C++ code into ObjC.  The operator==() that I am looking at compares its private members one-by-one and returns true iff they are all true.

**What is the equivalent implementation of operator==() in ObjC?**

From browsing, I see in ObjC:

- -isEqual
- -isEqualTo
- -isLike
- == (built-in?  not overrideable?)
- any others I missed?

*What is the protocol for these methods?  (deep or shallow comparison, etc...?)  Which one should I be using to replace an operator==() that compares all its members?*

Comment: `==` will only compare 2 object's pointer.  As simple as that, and you can't override it.  You will have to create your own method to compare your own classes.

Comment: Some discussion of `isEqual:` and `hash` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112373/implementing-hash-isequal-isequalto-for-objective-c-collections

Comment: @Monolo +1 for that useful link - ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isEqual:` is likely what you want to override. Also ensure that `hash` returns the same value for two objects that are equal.

There isn't really a protocol for comparison. Do whatever makes sense for your class. If you're comparing all members in your `operator==()` then that'd be deep comparison and yes, use `isEqual:`.

Comment: ty - accepted - too bad that there is no protocol for comparison - having so many different ones can definitely cause ambiguity/confusion.