# Multiple function calls in one line

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm translating a small java library to objective c. I'm having some trouble translating the following:

```
return other.tokens[0].equals(tokens[0]) &&
       other.tokens[1].equals(tokens[1]) &&
       other.tokens[2].equals(tokens[2]) &&
       other.tokens[3].equals(tokens[3]);
```

where other is an instance of a class, and tokens is a string array that is an instance variable of the same class. So far, what I have is this:

```
return ([other [[tokens[0] equals:tokens[0]]]] && 
        [other [[tokens[1] equals:tokens[1]]]] && 
        [other [[tokens[2] equals:tokens[2]]]] && 
        [other [[tokens[3] equals:tokens[3]]]]);
```

But I keep getting an "expected identifier" error, which I believe means I have something wrong with my syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have getToken method implementation in Quad class, you can use it with following implementation.

```
return ([[other getTokens:0] isEqualToString: [self getTokens[0]] &&
       [[other getTokens:1] isEqualToString: [self getTokens[1]] &&
       [[other getTokens:2] isEqualToString: [self getTokens[2]] &&
       [[other getTokens:3] isEqualToString: [self getTokens[3]]);
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about the get method. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life easy be breaking four conditions into 4 lines as:

```
BOOL b1=[other.tokens[0] isEqualTo:tokens[0]];
BOOL b2=[other.tokens[1] isEqualTo:tokens[1]];
BOOL b3=[other.tokens[2] isEqualTo:tokens[2]];
BOOL b4=[other.tokens[3] isEqualTo:tokens[3]];

return (b1 && b2 && b3 && b4);
```

Also, alternate way is iterate through all the values, if any one is `False` return `NO`:

```
for(NSInteger i=0; i<4; i++){
    if(![other.tokens[i] isEqualTo:tokens[i]]){
         return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
```

And read this, as I am not sure what kind of value are you comparing (Object / NSString / Number etc).. [Implementing -hash / -isEqual: / -isEqualTo...: for Objective-C collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112373/implementing-hash-isequal-isequalto-for-objective-c-collections)

Comment: I'm getting an error when using the above syntax, presumably due to the dot syntax, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Also, "tokens" is an NSArray.

Comment: "property 'tokens' not found on object of type 'quad *'". It's dealing with tokens as a property rather than an instant variable, which is due to the dot syntax used.

Comment: Now what is `quad`, your problem is increasing... cant solve without seeing full -relevant-code

Comment: I'm really sorry, but since I'm not sure of what exactly is the problem, I'm not able to exactly pin-point out all the relevant. Will this help? http://pastebin.com/BRrULVRL

Comment: There is no such method as isEqualTo in objective C. Please refers to documentation properly before posting any answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method "equals" in Objective C. If you are working on string comparison, it should be

```
[[token objectAtIndex: 0] isEqualToString:[token objectAtIndex: 0]]
```

but why you are comparing same strings.

Comment: I'm not comparing the same string. The first string is "other"'s instant variable. How do I add "other" to the first part of the code?